# One rectangle (two connected quads) with two textures - error with their common border

Tags: c++, mapping, directx, textures, blending

I have a rectangle consists of two quads (8 vertexes, I use indexed triangles):

```
------+------
| \   | \   |
|  \  |  \  |
|   \ |   \ |
______+______
```

I have also two textures for it. I bind both of them to the shader.

I want to texture one part of rectangle (left quad) with the first texture and the other part with the second one.

But when I choose the textures basing on the vertex's position in pixel shader, I have problem with the vertexes marked by "+". One time I'm analysing the "+" vertexes from the first quad, but the vertexes with the same position are also in the second quad (and have to have second texture on it). So setting the texture by the position will cause an error.

How to determinate which texture to assign (in sampler)? I don't want to make a second pass or add additional information to the shader (if there is any option to do it without it).

Basically speaking: I have model and the edge on it. That edge tells where the texture changes. But how to achieve that goal? When I set texture1 or texture2 on that edge's vertexes, there are some errors.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. Let's see if I understand correctly. You bind two textures to a shader. Inside the shader according to the value of the vertex? the value of the index? the value of the transformed vertex? you select which texture to sample. Did I understand correctly? I suggest editing your question to illustrate exactly what you do and in what order, in which shader the vertex or pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. Conditional branching in shaders will slow your shaders and should be avoided when possible. The reason for that is the shaders are optimized to execute the same code for each pixel in parallel. If you put conditions in the shader depending on the grphics card implementation one of the following will happen: Either the shader will execute both branches of the condition and select the appropriate path for each pixel after execution or will have all pixels wait until the longest path of the condition has finished executing before continuing.

In your case you are trying to draw one primitive with two textures. This is not really possible when defined in this way. The effect you want can be easily achieved if you change the concept:

I can think of two possible approaches (there may be more):

1. The first and the simplest is o draw two quads each with it's own texture. It's true you will call your shader twice but I hardly see any real slow down since the exact number of pixels is drawn anyway.
2. The second approach is somewhat more complicated but will enable you to draw just once. What you need to do is create one big texture containing your two textures one next to the other and map the entire texture to the entire triangle strip. This way the renderer will make sure for you that each quad gets its "own" texture. With OpenGl this is done using `glTexSubimage2D`. In direct3d 9 it is more complicated and you use the following sequence:

   A. Create the texture using `CreateTexture`

   B. Get surface for level 0 using `IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel()`

   C. Load the image into the surface using `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromMemory()` 

   D. Release the surface

So you map the horizontal texture coordinates from 0 to 0.5 to the vertices of the first quad and the coordinates from 0.5 to 1 to the vertices of the second quad. If the quads are not the same size or the textures are not the same size you just change the mapping accordingly

If you insist of using a condition branch in your shader you should remember that you are talking about a column of pixels not just about two vertices (this is a pixel shader after all) so you should check for all the pixels. This maybe a problem since there is no way for you to know the result of the transformation for each pixel unless there is no transformation. It is best not to query vertex values in a pixel shader.

Hope this gets you on the right track